# Android with thread shows error

Tags: android, thread-safety

In the application i called the Thread in the alerdialog click listener.
It shows the Error "Force to close the application" in the Mobile Samsung pro.
but when i execute the same code in the another application then code works correctly...

Comment: paste you logs here, to make it more clear.

Comment: -1 After 8 hours still no code to question, no comments to answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you're doing something wrong in the alerdialog click listener. Do the thing you're doing wrong right and it won't show the Error.

Answer (score 0):

Do this below procedure help full in ur app 
Android also provides something called AsyncTask which is specifically designed for running some stuff on a separate thread, and some on the UI thread. This automatically uses Android's threadpool, and if you do not have any reason to use an explicit separate thread, is an easy, clean way to go:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> { 
     // Runs on a ThreadPool thread 
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) { 
         int count = urls.length; 
         long totalSize = 0; 
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]); 
             // Sends data to onProgressUpdate to run on the UI thread 
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100)); 
         } 
         return totalSize; 
     } 

     // Runs on the UI thread! 
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) { 
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]); 
     } 

     // Runs on the UI thread! 
     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) { 
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes"); 
     } 
 }
```